# Couldn't understand use case for AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode

Tags: .net, oauth, access-token, adal, azure-active-directory

I couldn't find a use case for this overloaded method below,

AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode Method (String, Uri, ClientAssertion)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt459176.aspx

or similar ones which don't take resource as parameter, why would we request an access token which is not specifically for a resource.

I also tried it out and the access token returned is not JWT token, it’s kind of cryptic, looks similar to refresh token.

Comment: The resource parameter can be absent when the resource information is embedded in the authorization code itself, i.e. resource was specified when authorization code was obtained.

Comment: I haven't specified a resource and the call succeeds and I get an access token but it doesn't look like a JWT token.

Comment: Normally, the returned `AuthenticationResult.AccessToken` should be present and correct. Can you check the `AuthenticationResult.AccessTokenType`? What does it say?

Comment: It's showing "Bearer" and the access token looks more like the refresh token and/or authorization code, "AAABAAAA0TWEUN3YUUq5vuCv..."